# Why GXT simplecombobox is not properly working in Editor Grid?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using gxt Editor Grid, in which one of the column configured with Gxt 'SimpleComboBox'. When try to delete the value from the 'combobox', the value was reloading back. This strange behavior is only when i add the 'SimpleComboBox' to grid. If a add the same box to any other gxt components it is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set combo.setForceSelection(true);